# Xcode arc4random() not behaving as expected

Tags: xcode, arc4random

I have the following inputs (verified by NSLog): `xleft = 128, xRight = 192`. The next line of code uses these-

```
xPos = (arc4random() % xRight-xleft) + xleft;
```

On the last run, xPos = 53. By my calculations, it should be no less than 128 if the random number produced is zero `(192 - 128 = 64, rand(64) = 0, 0 + 128 = 128`. I am trying to generate random numbers in the range xLeft to xRight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
xPos = (arc4random() % (xRight-xleft)) + xleft;
```

Basically you're modding by xRIght and then subtracting xleft, instead of first subtracting xleft from xright and modding with the result.

Reference link: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_2.0_Operator_Precedence

Comment: Thanks, it was the modulus precedence that I was missing, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

% has higher precedence in C and directly derived languages like Objective-C than + and -. It's equal to * and /.

So that expression is evaluated as:

1. Get arc4random
2. Get the modulus of that and xRight
3. Subtract xLeft
4. Add xLeft

So you should expect anything in the range [0, xRight)

Comment: Many thanks, it was the modulus precedence that I was missing, cheers.